# Avoid invoking controller method for visted pages

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using JSF and primefaces to develop my UI and using Java and Spring as server side.

In an xhtml page I am calling a controller method which will perform some logics and populates a HashMap in the bean class. In xhtml, the HashMap is been iterated using JSTL foreach loop to create the UI components. I have multiple pages in y application. So each xhtml page willl have previous and next buttons.

Consider, i have **Page_1, Page_2, Page_3**. All there pasges has set of radio buttons and check boxes. In each page i have next and previous buttons. On click of **next** button **page_1**, **page_2** will be displayed. On click of **previous** button in **page_2**, **page_1** will be displayed.

Each page wil call a controller method.

```
Page_1 (radio_buttons) <------> Page_2(check_boxes) <------> Page_3
```

My question is, if user checks/selects a radio button/checkbox in page_1 and go to page_2 sing next button in page_1 and when he returns back to page_1, how will I make the radio button to remain in selected state??

The bean which hold the selected radio button/check box values are resetting in the controller method when the page load. So i need to restrict from calling the controller if the page loads for second time. How can i achieve this?

Comment: to keep the state, every time you change from one page to another, you must actually submit these values and keep them in a session (or any equivalent mechanism).

Comment: Just use 1 view with conditionally rendered content.